# Java BigInteger to the intValue

Tags: java, encryption, integer, static-methods, biginteger

Im trying to practice the 'Affine Cipher' with the Java code. I tried to use the modInverse() function in BigInteger class. I have to put some integer values in the modInverse function. Therefore, I used the BigInteger.valueOf(Integer) to get the ModInverse of the integer number. But the problem occurs here, when I tried to change the BigInteger value to the integer, it gives me an error that "Can not make a static reference to the non-static method modInverse(BigInteger) from the type BigInteger. How should I fix the problem?

here is my code:

```
for(int a = 1; a<=25;a++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b<=26; b++)
            {
                for(int i  =0; i < cipherText.length;i++)
                {
                    cipherText[i] = (byte) ( ((cipherText[i]-'A')-b)* (BigInteger.modInverse(BigInteger.valueOf(a)).intValue() % 26 + 'A' );
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BigInteger is the class name.  When you do `BigInteger.someMethod` you are assuming that `someMethod` is a `static` method.  In this case it isn't.  It is an `instance` method so you need an instance of the `BigInteger` class to use it.  Here is an example using `b and c` which are relatively prime.

```
BigInteger b = BigInteger.valueOf(33);
BigInteger c = BigInteger.valueOf(14);
int v = b.mod(c).intValue();
System.out.println(v);
v = c.modInverse(b).intValue();
System.out.println(v);
```

Prints

```
5
26
```